# [Form][2.7] In entity field type with multiple choice not set selected data

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a problem https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15586.

Someone could help me?

Comment: The fix for this problem was solved with the last update to the 2.7.4 version of Symfony released yesterday night.

Comment: Yes.. Right.. Problem solved in Symfony 2.7.4